# another Must declare the scalar variable Error

Tags: t-sql

I have been trying to modify data in a temporary table using cursor and substring function. All works fine when I do all the separate steps via selects, but as soon as I put them together and start it it gives me the error message: Must declare the scalar variable "@tempvar1". These doesn't seem as two or more batches and I can't figure out why it isn't working.

```
declare @temptabulka table
(
ID_Studenta uniqueidentifier,
NAME varchar(120)
)
Insert into @temptabulka (ID_Studenta, NAME) SELECT ID_Studenta,NAME FROM STUDENTS

DECLARE @tempvarA varchar(120)
DECLARE @tampvar1 varchar(120)

DECLARE prvykurzor CURSOR FOR
SELECT NAME
FROM @temptabulka

OPEN prvykurzor
FETCH NEXT FROM prvykurzor INTO @tempvar1

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
SET @tempvarA = @tampvar1
SET @tempvarA = substring(@tempvarA,0,
            CASE            
               WHEN patindex('%_Nez. Priez %',@tempvarA)=0  
                THEN len(@tempvarA)+1
               ELSE patindex('%_Nez. Priez %',@tempvarA)        
            END
             )    

UPDATE @temptabulka SET NAME = @tempvarA
WHERE NAME = @tampvar1
FETCH NEXT FROM prvykurzor INTO @tempvar1
END

CLOSE prvykurzor
DEALLOCATE prvy_cursor
```

Answer (score 2):

You have declared the variable as `tampvar1` not `tempvar1` and also use it with the wrong name. Replace all `tampvar1` with `tempvar1` and you should be fine.

here: `DECLARE @tampvar1 varchar(120)`

here: `SET @tempvarA = @tampvar1`

here: `WHERE NAME = @tampvar1`

Comment: It happens to the best of us

Comment: @MikeM Heh, yeah it sure does.